# How do I check if the base-$b$ representation of my number contains the same digits?

Tags: number-bases

I came up with the following exercise with the intention of learning *Mathematica* but I am already stuck in the beginning. Let $ n,b $ denote positive integers with $ n>0 $ and $ b\geq2 $. My aim is to check whether the base-$ b $ representation of $ n $ contains the same digits in base $ b $.

For instance, $ n=63_{10} $ has the representation $ n=111111_2 $ in base $ b=2 $ and $ n=124_{10} $ is $ n=444_5 $ in base $ b=5 $.

I know that *Mathematica* can easily convert between two different bases using `BaseForm[expr, base]`, but I have no idea how to efficiently verify whether the digits of the resulting number are all the same. I was looking for functions that work with repunits, but I found none. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at `IntegerDigits` (and, if you should ever need it, its inverse `FromDigits`). For example, `IntegerDigits[63, 2]` returns `{1,1,1,1,1,1}` and `IntegerDigits[124, 5]` returns `{4,4,4}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @HenrikSchumacher mentioned, `IntegerDigits` works:

```
allSameQ[n_, b_] := Equal @@ IntegerDigits[n, b]

allSameQ @@@ {{63, 2}, {124, 5}}
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!